# Do any private charter schools sponsor your pilot school tuition?

Tags: flight-school

Do any US or European private charters pay for your jet pilot school in exchange for contract pilot service?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Jet training is expensive, very expensive. They still have to pay you afterwards, so they aren't getting a lot (they can't make you an indentured servant). There are a couple big commercial operators that do this, like Lufthansa but the number of "slots" available is very limited and there is a huge demand for it, so they only take unusually qualified individuals, and the "free" school is structured as a deferred loan that you pay back during employment.

Comment: thank you. I will step with that info and pay my bills from the first rung on the ladder.